# Proper syntax for hiding folders and subfolders from search engines with robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt

I have a folder on my website /pics.
It has many subfolders.
Each of the subfolders contains files.
I wish to hide /pics and its subfolders and the files of the subfolders from search engines.

Which of the following do I use, or are they synonymous:

```
Disallow: /pics
Disallow: /pics/
Disallow: /pics/*
```

And if they are not synonymous, what is the difference in effect between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not synonymous.

The `Disallow` value always represents **the beginning** of a URL path. So, `Disallow: /pics/` doesn’t  block `https://example.com/pics`, and `Disallow: /pics` also blocks `https://example.com/picsandmore`.

`Disallow: /pics/*` is a special case: In the original robots.txt specification, the `*` has no special meaning, it’s a character like any other (so it would block a URL like `https://example.com/pics/*foo`). But many search engines extended the robots.txt specification and interpret `*` as placeholder for any string (including the empty string). This would be equivalent to `Disallow: /pics/`, though, so it’s better not to use the `*` variant in this case.

If you also want to block `https://example.com/pics` (without trailing slash), you have to use `Disallow: /pics`. But keep in mind that it also blocks any other URL with a path that starts with `/pics`.

If there is no `https://example.com/pics`, so there’s always a trailing slash, you can use the more restrictive `Disallow: /pics/`.

And if you want to hide the fact that there is a `pics` folder, you could use `Disallow: /p`, or `Disallow: /pi`, etc. But, again, keep in mind that it might block more than you want.

Comment: Thank you. So if I want to block the subfolders of pics and their files, and I have no files in pics itself, then both of my first 2 options would work?

Comment: @oyvey: Yes. If you don’t have a document at `/pics` which you want to block, I would go with `Disallow: /pics/`.